# View Controller trouble in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I just now figured out how to add a new view when you press a button. For example, in my storyboard, I am using a tabbed controller and in my first viewController i have a button in the top right corner on a navigation bar. and when i press that button, it directs to another view controller. I was wondering how I would be able to write the code for that view controller? I tried creating a new file > objective-c class, but I dont know how to link them together? any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've made that other controller in the storyboard, you just change the class of that controller to your new class that you made. You do this in the identity inspector.

Comment: I'm confused.. Do i need to create a new objective-c class? cause when i create that new class.. i changed the class of the controller in the storyboard to the matching class that i just created.. but when i click on the view controller in storyboard and then the assistant editor.. i cannot edit the code for that view controller... @rdelmar

Comment: Yes, you create a new objective-c class of whatever type you want your controller to be (UIViewController, UITableViewController, etc.).

Comment: Ya but I did change the class in the identity inspector and everything, but i still don't know how to edit the code for that view controller... @rdelmar

Comment: You go into the .h and .m files that you created and write code. If you don't know how to do that, then you have a lot of learning to do.

Comment: sorry i figured it out.. i couldn't figure out how to connect the textFields in the code with the textFields in the storyboard through the assistant editor.. But I got it! thanks @rdelmar

Answer (score 1):

Use navigation controller to navigate between your view's, You have to make an IBACTION method fot the button. In which you will navigate the view you want by pushviewcontroller.

Please see this link...

[How to push viewcontroller ( view controller )?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644293/how-to-push-viewcontroller-view-controller)

Answer (score 1):

It implies that which class has to be initialized and what is the nib name of this class. We should not do anything in this block, until you need that your code to be executed before viewDidLoad/viewWillAppear.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that there is no code necessary to get a button to direct you to another view controller that you set up. You have to declare the button obviously in the `@interface` part, connect the button with it's code, and then you have to use an action connection from the button to the next view controller you want the button to activate. I have used a modal connection personally, mainly because I'm not sure what a push connection is or what it does... But Ya I figured it out! Hope this helps to any other people who need this!